# Error while trying to run a shell script that connects to a VM and executes some commands on it

Tags: windows, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

My code:

```
gcloud compute instances create mongodb --zone europe-west3-a --image-family coreos-stable \
--image-project coreos-cloud --tags http-server
gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west3-a mongodb \
--command="some_commands"
```

It creates the google instance nicely but when it tries to ssh, an error comes up:

```
WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!
The server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has
cached in the registry. This means that either the
server administrator has changed the host key, or you
have actually connected to another computer pretending
to be the server. Update cached key? (y/n, Return cancels connection) Server refused our key
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
```

How can I skip this annoying prompt? Take into account that I must create a new instance, I cannot do ssh to one that already exists.

Comment: Adding another gcloud compute ssh solved partially the problem because everything worked fine but it required me to click "yes" during the first ssh. Ideally, I'd like to avoid manual intervention.